# get pinch to zoom on one single word of a paragraph

Tags: android

how to get pinch to zoom on one single word of a paragraph. I want to get the focus on that particular word after zooming. how do i do it? kindly, help me out

Answer (score 0):

may this help

[Image in Canvas with touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743328/android-image-in-canvas-with-touch-events/5747233#5747233)

Comment: i have already used the above mentioned code. but i am unable to get the above criteria which i want to get

Comment: i want to get the focus on the word where i perform pinch zoom. Zoom and everything i am getting. Is there any method for that.

Comment: what is mid point zoom. not particularly one word. but the portion of the paragraph where i zoom. i want to show the same portion of paragraph after zooming.