# Positioning Bitmap on Canvas

Tags: java, android

forgive me if its a simple question but I am stuck. 
I am trying to set the position of my image to the left of the screen by certain distance (-150).
It works fine with positive numbers, but not with negative. 
I am drawing it on canvas since I will be adding more images to the resultant bitmap (result) later.
Here is my code

```
     Bitmap image2=resizedbitmap;

     result = Bitmap.createBitmap(image2.getWidth(), image2.getHeight(),             `   `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);        
     canvas = new Canvas(result);//Create the canvas to an image                
     srcRect = new Rect(-150, 0, result.getWidth(), result.getHeight());//does not work with negative numbers
     destRect = new Rect(srcRect);
     destRect.offset(0, 0);//if negative cuts the image
     canvas.drawBitmap(image2, srcRect, destRect, null);
```

Am I missing something? Any help appreciated.
Many tnx in advance

Comment: Isn't  `new Rect (0,0, width, height)` the left top corner ?

Comment: yes it is but I want to set it to new Rect(-150,0).. with i.e. new Rect(150,0) it sets it to the right off the screen but not with -150 :(

Comment: So with -150 it should be 150 units **outside** the screen to the left ?

Comment: Because with +150 it places a bitmap to the right I believe it should do the same with -150 to the left, but this is the issue at the moment

Comment: so yeah **outside** of the scree to the left

Answer (score -1):

rather using this, see here
[Image in Canvas with touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743328/android-image-in-canvas-with-touch-events/5747233#5747233)