# android - how to move image when clicked?

Tags: android, image, listener

I try to make an application which place a certain png file in the screen with coordinates, and when the user clicks it, the image will move to another location in the screen.

can you guys give the sample..?? I'm kinda confused on how to draw the image (using bitmap or button??) and how to move it ??

THX for the answer...

Answer (score 0):

refer this
[Image in Canvas with touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743328/android-image-in-canvas-with-touch-events/5747233#5747233)