# How to manipulate images in android canvas?

Tags: android

i am having an image in canvas.i want to get color at  particular pixels and replace with user defined color.is it possible to do for abitmap placed in  android canvas?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `Canvas` is more like a write-only object: you can draw on the `Bitmap`, but you can't really get almost any information on the `Bitmap`. But if you have access to the `Bitmap` itself, this is a very easy task: just use `Bitmap.getPixel(int x, int y)` to get the color of the pixels and then draw whatever you need on the `Canvas` or even just call `Bitmap.setPixel(int x, int y, int color)` without creating any `Canvas` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. just bitmap.getPixel(x, y) and setPixel(x, y, color). Make sure that the bitmap your working on is mutable.

Answer (score 0):

[Image in Canvas with touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743328/android-image-in-canvas-with-touch-events/5747233#5747233)