# how using MotionEvent when move between two button without rise a finger

Tags: android

i try to make my button to be accessible by talkback everytime it get focused/selected,
i use this `public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {`

```
switch ( event.getAction() ) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
v.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SELECTED);
break;}
```

it is work when first time i touch a button, but when i move to next button without rise my finger, the button dont have focus, and talkback cant speak it, how i can use sendaccesibilityevent to my current button?

i try to use ACTION_MOVE, but i still need to rise my finger so the second button can have focus
thanx, and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

[Image in Canvas with touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743328/android-image-in-canvas-with-touch-events/5747233#5747233)