# How to create and draw a progress bar that is created in a class that extends from View

Tags: android, view, progress-bar

I want to know if it is possible to create a progress bar that is created in a class that extends from the class View?

My intention is to add a progress bar in my animation, using the "On a View" structure for creating animations in android:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html

I tried with the fallowing way, in the view class, but it didn't appear.

```
public class CustomDrawableView extends View {
    private ProgressBar mProgress;

    public CustomDrawableView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mProgress = new ProgressBar(context, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        mProgress.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Greetings

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score -3):

try this
[Image in Canvas with touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743328/android-image-in-canvas-with-touch-events/5747233#5747233)