# Moving a view with a finger

Tags: android, android-layout

I began to study Android not so long ago and have a question relating to which approach I should use to solve the simple task. Let's suppose I have a view (maybe, a button) and I want user to be able to move it across the screen with a finger. Until AbsoluteLayout was deprecated, the right approach seamed obvious. I would've just changed position of my view based on corresponding events. But what is right now?

Answer (score 5):

Create a custom view of your own and add a onTouch event listener. It is very simple. Explained very well [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html).

Comment: I'll read that. Though that article seams to me a bit 'too much' as for my simple problem...

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to move your views in order to navigate through your application or page through images in a gallery, Android provides a collection of [widgets](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/package-summary.html) to do things like that.  If you're trying to, say, pan across a large image, maybe this will help:  [Image in Canvas with touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743328/android-image-in-canvas-with-touch-events)

Answer (score 0):

Im using FrameLayout and update marginLeft and marginTop

You can add multiple children to frame layout, though this is not recommended because of multiple resolutions issues.

from the [android docs:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display
>   a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single
>   child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a
>   way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children
>   overlapping each other. You can, however, add multiple children to a
>   FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by
>   assigning gravity to each child, using the android:layout_gravity
>   attribute.

This "warning" is not applicable in your case because you are explicitly setting the margins according to the user  touch event.

Comment: That's appropriate only for one view and there may be several views in container.

Comment: you can add several views to frame layout.