# How to squish pixels on android 2.2 (and above)

Tags: android, android-intent, image, pixel, pinch

i want to be able to take my fingers pinch them together to squish a part of my image and then  have the image instantly revert to original form and do the opposite and bloat that one part of the picture up and revert to original 
How would i do this???

Comment: This is a rather broad question, and not really about programming since it doesn't sound like you've written any code yet.  Is there something more specific that you don't understand?

Comment: no this is programming i just dont know how i would start to make this is i already have an activity where i take a picture and it puts the picture on the screen from there i want to be able to use my fingers to squish certain parts of the image or vice versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I think this may be what you are looking for: 
[Android Image in Canvas with Touch Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743328/android-image-in-canvas-with-touch-events). You are going to need to spend some more time reading up on what APIs are provided in Android. I would also recommend going through each item in the API Demos app and look at the source since its provided.